# How do I split a tar.gz file into multiple files in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have this command `split -b 1800k file_name.tar.gz` but don't know how to use this in Dart or Flutter.

I have a tar.gz file and I want to split it into multiple files in JSON format. Is this possible in Dart?

For example,
One original File: `file_name.tar.gz`

After splitting:
`file_name_1.json, file_name_2.json, file_name_3.json, file_name_4.json, file_name_5.json`

Comment: Maybe it would be worth trying to do this in Dart? And then do it in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this

I have made the below Function to Split files into multiple segments.

```
Future<List<File>> splitFileInSegment(File file,
      {int chunkSize = 1800,
      required String cachePath,
      required String fileName}) async {
    int sizeOfFile = chunkSize * 1024;
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load(file.path);
    List<int> bytes = bd.buffer.asUint8List();

    List<List<int>> splitBytes = [];

    int isHalfFileNeeded = bytes.length % sizeOfFile;
    int numberOfFiles = bytes.length ~/ sizeOfFile;
    if (isHalfFileNeeded > 0) {
      numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles + 1;
    }
    int offset = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
      int getLastIndex = 0;

      int bytesReached = (i + 1) * sizeOfFile;
      if (bytesReached <= bytes.length) {
        getLastIndex = bytesReached;
      } else {
        getLastIndex = offset + isHalfFileNeeded;
      }

      List<int> byteList = bytes.sublist(offset, getLastIndex);
      splitBytes.add(byteList);
      offset += sizeOfFile;
    }

    List<File> files = [];

    for (int index = 0; index < splitBytes.length; index++) {
      final File tempFile = File("$cachePath/$fileName" + "_" + "$index.json");

      File file = await tempFile.writeAsBytes(splitBytes[index]);
      files.add(file);
    }

    return files;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  File originalFile = File('file_name.tar.gz');

  List<int> bytes = originalFile.readAsBytesSync();

  int chunkSize = 1800 * 1024; // 1800 KB

  int numOfFiles = (bytes.length / chunkSize).ceil();

  for (int i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {

    int start = i * chunkSize;

    int end = (i + 1) * chunkSize;

    if (end > bytes.length) {

      end = bytes.length;

    }

    List<int> chunk = bytes.sublist(start, end);

    File newFile = File('file_name_${i + 1}.json');

    newFile.writeAsBytesSync(chunk);

  }

  print('File split into $numOfFiles JSON files.');
}
```

Comment: File() is not working for me as I have a local package and I have to fetch the tar file from the local package assets. This is not working for me.